# Unable to filter pivot table using VBA from powerpivot

Tags: excel, vba, loops, filter, pivot-table

[PivotSummary1 - Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwmUL.jpg)
[Table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R66Bb.jpg)

The above pivot table is generated from a powerpivot.

I have a code to loop through the filter and perform task and it works for normal pivot table, but not from powerpivot pivot table.

I record a macro to perform a filter and tried to replay but it gave me runtime error 1004.

Macro2 works on normal pivot table, Macro1 does not work on powerpivot pivot table.

```
Sub Macro2()
' Macro2 Macro (Normal Pivot Table)
'
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotSummary").PivotFields("Name").ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotSummary").PivotFields("Name").CurrentPage = "A"
End Sub

Sub Macro1()
' Macro1 Macro (Powerpivot Pivot Table)
'
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotSummary1").PivotFields("[Table2].[Name].[Name]"). _
    ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotSummary1").PivotFields("[Table2].[Name].[Name]"). _
    CurrentPageName = "[Table2].[Name].&[A]"
End Sub
```

What is wrong here? Since i can't reference it, i can't get the same result i do with normal pivot table.